# How to iterate through 100k items one by one in mongodb and mongomapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I am using mongomapper for the mongodb queries.
I have checked that using My_Modeal.all() returns a cursor for the specific collection of documents.

I wanted to perform .each() on each document, but it turns out that before processing .each() this command takes really long time to process (40 seconds).

How can I process all documents, one by one without delays, just like in the MySQL? (select * from table)

Comment: Maybe this is a pointer in the right direction: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/

Comment: not really, batch will continue, once it's finished, I can do each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the common ActiveRecord method `find_each` for this use case (and for other datastores).  For example:

```
MyModeal.find_each {|object| do_something(object) }
```

Behind the scenes, MongoMapper is issuing a MongoDB `find` which returns an enumerable cursor.  The `find_each` method will iterate through the cursor, yielding one MongoMapper object at a time.